# How to make the picture appear in the list

Tags: android, database, android-room, adapter

I have a recycler view that works with this adapter. In the database I have a key, a name and an image that is converted into a photo. But if I restart the program, the picture is not displayed in the list, and if I add new data to the database, the picture stops being displayed in the list.

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.NoteViewHolder> {

```
private SortedList<Note> sortedList;

public Adapter() {
    sortedList = new SortedList<>(Note.class, new SortedList.Callback<Note>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Note o1, Note o2) {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(Note oldItem, Note newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(Note item1, Note item2) {
            return item1.uid == item2.uid;
        }

        @Override
        public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    });
}

@NonNull
@NotNull
@Override
public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new NoteViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false)
    );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(sortedList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return sortedList.size();
}

public void setItems(List<Note> notes) {
    sortedList.replaceAll(notes);
}

static class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Uri uri;

    Note note;

    public NoteViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
        super (itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CreateActivity.start((Activity) itemView.getContext(), note);
            }
        });
    }

    public void bind (Note note) {
        this.note = note;

        uri = Uri.parse(note.img);
        textView.setText(note.text);
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried using glide to load the image using the uri instead ?

Answer (score 0):

try using Glide instead, to include Glide in your project add this lines to build.Gradle(Module App) in the dependencies section :

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
...
}
```

then try to load the image using this line of code instead of         `imageView.setImageURI(uri);` :

```
   Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

you would need a context object though, so if you can pass a Fragment/Activity Context through in the bind method (or any another Context or Fragment or Activity object would do the job.).

as an example you can store the `itemView.getContext()` context or the itemView itself as a global variable and use it when you need in bind method.